# R: Merging dataframes

Tags: r, merge

I am looking to merge to dataframes, but the manner in which I would like to merge them is a bit uncommon.

I will illustrate with an example:

> ```
> Matrix1
> Col1 Col2 Vol VWAP Value  
> ABC    1   2    4   8
> ABC    2   3    5   15  
> DEF    1   8    9   72  
> DEF    2   8    9   72  
>
> Matrix 2  
> Col1 Col2 Vol VWAP Value  
> ABC   1     4   7   28  
> ABC   2     5   1   5  
> HIJ   1     6   6   36  
> HIJ   2     7   3   21
> ```

I would like to then get the following matrix:

Matrix3

> ```
> Col1 Col2 Vol VWAP Value
> ABC   1    6   6    36  
> ABC   2    8   2.5  20
> DEF   1    8   9    72
> DEF   2    8   9    72
> HIJ   1    6   6    36
> HIJ   2    7   3    21
> ```

In the first two matrices the VWAP column is just the Value column divided by the Vol column.
The third matrix combines the first two in the following manner: If the first two Cols are the same, add the Vol and Value cols of the matching rows. If there is no match, just add the unmatched rows to the end of the matrix. The VWAP column of Matrix3 is then again just the Value col divided by the Vol col.

I tried the following:

```
Matrix3 = merge(Matrix1 ,Matrix2, all = TRUE)  
Matrix3[,4] = Matrix3[,5]/Matrix3[,3]
```

but for some reason it isn't summing the Vol or the Value columns. I have checked, and the first column is a character, while the rest are either numeric/integer.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Mike

Comment: What's the result of your merge? I don't see where the summation should happen in your code. I guess you should get Matrix3 with Vol.X and Vol.Y. I suggest that you specify the by-parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you treat them as data frames, you can append them first using `rbind()` then use `ddply()' to summarize the Vol, Value, and calculate the V

```
df1<-data.frame(Col1=c("ABC","ABC","DEF","DEF"),
                Col2=c(1,2,1,2),
                Vol=c(2,3,8,8),
                VWAP=c(4,5,9,9),
                Value=c(8,15,72,72))  

df2<-data.frame(Col1=c("ABC","ABC","HIJ","HIJ"),
                Col2=c(1,2,1,2),
                Vol=c(4,5,6,7),
                VWAP=c(7,1,6,3),
                Value=c(28,5,36,21))  

merged=rbind(df1,df2)             # stick the dfs together
require(plyr)                     # library
ddply(merged,
     .(Col1,Col2),
     summarize,
     Vol=sum(Vol),
     VWAP=sum(Value)/sum(Vol),
     Value=sum(Value))

  Col1 Col2 Vol VWAP Value
1  ABC    1   6  6.0    36
2  ABC    2   8  2.5    20
3  DEF    1   8  9.0    72
4  DEF    2   8  9.0    72
5  HIJ    1   6  6.0    36
6  HIJ    2   7  3.0    21
```

Comment: In addition to this answer I highly recommend reading about the [Split-Apply-Combine Strategy](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v40/i01/paper).

Answer (score 1):

First a comment on notation: Don't call your `data.frame` Matrix1. In `R` the classes `matrix` and `data.frame` are different.

Anyway, the merge command cannot possibly know that it is supposed to add your "Value" and "Vol" columns. You should first merge and then take care of the addition afterwards. Here's how you can solve this:

```
m3 <- merge(Matrix1, Matrix2, by=c("Col1", "Col2"), all=TRUE)
# add vol and value
m3[, "Vol"] <- rowSums(m3[, c("Vol.x", "Vol.y")], na.rm=TRUE)
m3[, "Value"] <- rowSums(m3[, c("Value.x", "Value.y")], na.rm=TRUE)
# divide to get vwap
m3[, "VWAP"] <- m3[, "Value"]/m3[, "Vol"]
# extract result
res <- m3[, c("Col1", "Col2", "Vol", "VWAP", "Value")]
res 
##    Col1 Col2 Vol VWAP Value
##  1  ABC    1   6  6.0    36
##  2  ABC    2   8  2.5    20
##  3  DEF    1   8  9.0    72
##  4  DEF    2   8  9.0    72
##  5  HIJ    1   6  6.0    36
##  6  HIJ    2   7  3.0    21
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it manullay:

```
id <- mat1$Col1 %in% mat2$Col1 &
    mat1$Col2 %in% mat2$Col2

mat1[id,c('Vol')] <- colSums(rbind(mat1[id,c('Vol')],
                    mat2[id,c('Vol')]))

mat1[id,c('Value')] <- colSums(rbind(mat1[id,c('Value')],
                                     mat2[id,c('Value')]))

m3 <- rbind(mat1,mat2[!id,])

m3[, "VWAP"] <- m3[, "Value"]/m3[, "Vol"]

# Col1 Col2 Vol VWAP Value
# 1   ABC    1   6  6.0    36
# 2   ABC    2   8  2.5    20
# 3   DEF    1   8  9.0    72
# 4   DEF    2   8  9.0    72
# 31  HIJ    1   6  6.0    36
# 41  HIJ    2   7  3.0    21
```